# My 5 years old Samsung Washer Keeps Tripping my gfci (Reason is Ground Fault)

Tags: circuit-breaker, washer, ground, weatherstripping

I moved into a new house several months ago, and this house uses Eaton 20A GFCI breaker.
My 5 years old Samsung Washer keeps tripping the breaker, and this breaker's diagnosis says that it's because Gould Fault (5 times flash lights on the tester).

I do not know what should I do. Do I need to replace the Washer?

Answer (score 3):

New houses are supposed to have dedicated circuits for the laundry room.

Nonetheless, unplug the washing machine.  See if the GFCI trips stop, or continue. (if they continue, it's NOT the washer and is something else on the circuit).

Another diagnostic test you can do since it's GFCI protected (NOT for using continuously!!!) is to get a 2-prong "cheater".  Carefully insulate the ground prong so it cannot contact the receptacle in any way.  We're trying to disconnect ground *as a diagnostic test*.  Plug the washer through this ground-insulated cheater, and see if the GFCI trips continue or go away.  If the trips stop with the cheater that test proves the washing machine is faulty.

A repairman should be able to unplug components inside the washer until it stops tripping GFCIs; that would indicate which component is faulty.  It might be resolvable via cleaning (lint from dryer on components, + humidity, might cause a ground fault), or replacement of that component.

Answer (score 1):

A ground fault is a potentially serious problem. It can be caused by worn out insulation, water leaking onto electric connections or a number of other problems. The problem is most likely somewhere in the washing machine. Start by narrowing down when it happens:

- start of cycle
- start of spin/drain
  etc.

That will hopefully keep narrow down the source of the problem. Unlikely with a 5 year old machine that you'll need to replace it. More likely it will need a repair of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to replace the machine, or get a repairer to find out what's wrong.

There are several possible things it could be, all of them are a problem that needs to be fixed:-

- The heating element has failed and water is getting in to it.
- Water is leaking out and on to the electrics in the washer.
- A wire is chafing against some metalwork in the washer and shorting out.